# UITableView grouped and .plist

Tags: uitableview, plist

I wanted to make a sectioned UITableView using plist.
Originally, my plist was structured this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>First</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>First</string>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>image.png</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Second</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>SecondR</string>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>image.png</string>
    </dict>

//etc
</array>
</plist>
```

[image]

Where `name` was the name of the rows and of the `rowNamed` label in my `detailView`, description was for the string in my ´detailView`and ìmage`the UIImageView in the `detailView`.

The cell.textLabel.text did show the `name` key this way:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Now,following the answer in this question, [sectioned UITableView sourced from a pList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850659/sectioned-uitableview-sourced-from-a-plist), I created my new plist file with section, structured this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>   Section1</string>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Test</string>
                <key>description</key>
                <string>test</string>
                <key>image</key>
                <string>testtttt</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>   Section2</string>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Test</string>
                <key>description</key>
                <string>test</string>
                <key>image</key>
                <string>testtttt</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

[image]

The point is that now i don't know how to make it similar to the previous plist structure (i mean, image,name and description), and i don't know how to make `cellForRowAtIndexPath` show the `name` key contained in `Rows` as title of the cells. I tried with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[sortedList objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But i get an empty cell.

I want cell.textLabel.text to show the key `name` for each element (row) contained in each section 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `plist` is an array of `dictionaries`. Each `dictionary` represents a `section`.
And `rows` within a `section` is present as an `array` whose `key` is `Rows` in that `section`/`dictionary`.
So to get a `row` in a particular `section`, first get the `section`. Then get the `row` using `objectForKey:@"Rows"`.

Once you have rows `array`, it again contains the several `rows` as a `dictionary`.

```m
NSDictionary *section = [sortedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *rows = [section objectForKey:@"Rows"];
cell.textLabel.text = [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```