# plist for the group table view

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

i am new in xcode, and i am writing a table view, which load from my plist, and i would use the group style for the table view, and the section header would be the month, and each month of cell will have the name, date and image. below are my plist, i don't even confirm am i right to set up the plist like that, that can be show on the table view, would any people help, how to convert these plist into different section of header and the cell, i would really appreicate that.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2xqcmeg3f68aue/screenShot.png

Answer (score 0):

Plist is actually a dictionary containing your data. Your dictionary contains an array of sections. Each element of array intern contains a dictionary, which is the section data - rows, and cell content. So you can fetch data from plist and then pass that to table view data source methods.

You can check this thread for some more detailed info - 
[UITableView grouped and .plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963845/uitableview-grouped-and-plist)