# Setting UITableViewCell Title from Plist String

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist, xcode4.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sectioned UITableView sourced from a pList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850659/sectioned-uitableview-sourced-from-a-plist)

I am having a hard time trying to set the text label of the cell to the values of the strings in my plist. The app crashes on `cell.textlabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. I'm pretty sure everything else is good, just don't know that last part. Thanks in advance.

Here is my plist:

```
Root - Array
    Item 0 - Dictionary
        Key 0 - Array
            Item 0 - String - Value 0
        Key 1 - Array
            Item 1 - String - Value 1
```

Here are my tableview data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return _objects.count;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSDictionary *dict = [_objects objectAtIndex:section];
return [dict.allValues count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

NSArray *array = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Here is a link that answered my question perfectly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850659/sectioned-uitableview-sourced-from-a-plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the structure of your `_object` is not clear. I am assuming it refers to `Item 0 - Dictionary` in the plist.

in `numberOfRowsInSection:` you refer to it as a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [_objects objectAtIndex:section]
```

while in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you refer to it as an array:

```
NSArray *array = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

anyway, if my assumption is correct then change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code to the following:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSarray *array = [dict objectForKey:myKey]; //myKey is whatever key you are assigning
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

well you can restructure your plist to achieve that. You basically just get rid of the `dictionary` level.. try something like this:

```
Root - Array
    Item 0 - Array                   <-- this is a section
        Item 0 - String - Value 0    <-- this is a cell
    Item 1 - Array                   <-- section
        Item 0 - String - Value 1    <-- cell
```

Comment: I set `_objects` as an array using `arrayWithContentsOfFile` and the file being my plist. Maybe I am going about it wrong. The result now is two cells (without sections) in my table and only the first having a title being "Value 0." The end result I want is to create a table with sections and items in each section. How would I do this? Is the structure of my plist wrong or is the problem my data source methods? @KDaker

Comment: All right, thanks! I thought it was bad programming "grammar" to have an array directly enclosed by another. I guess I was wrong.